# Basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ spanned by vectors $(1,3,-1,2,3)$, $(2,7,-2,5,2),$ and $(1,4,-1,3,-1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ spanned by vectors $(1,3,-1,2,3)$, $(2,7,-2,5,2),$ and $(1,4,-1,3,-1)$.
>
> How can I find a basis for $W$ and what is the dimension of $W$?

I know I will create a matrix by using vectors as columns of matrix and reduce it to row echelon form but I don't know what to do after than.

And also, how can I find a basis for complement of $W$ and what will be the relationship between basis of $W$ and its complement?

Comment: I know that but I have problems with calculations I found dimW as 2 and dimW complement as 2 but they dont add up to 5. I don't even need explanations I just need to learn where I did my mistake while reducing it to row echelon form because I am tilted.

Comment: Find the equations of $W$ (there will be  $3$ linearly independent equations), then $3$ linearly independent vectors which do not satisfy these equations.

Comment: I need to create a matrix with using stated vectors as a column vector right?

Comment: Yes, and perform the same row operations  to obtain the conditions that ensure the augmented matrix has the same rank.

Comment: to find a basis for complement for W then I will use stated vectors as row vectors then I will find null(W) but addition of complement W and original W doesn't add up to 5. Can you confirm me please ? I really need help I dont know where I am doing mistake.

Comment: What do you denote null(W)? The orthogonal subspace?

Comment: If you want someone to check your work, then show it! Edit your question to include your calculations up to the point where you’re getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You may first check if the three vectors are linearly independent, if this is the case then they're the basis themselves, if one of them is made up from two others then remove that one, the other two will still span the same space as the removed one is a linear combination of these two, you can remove one by one as long as you can to reach a linearly independent set which spans the whole subspace, this is the basis, and the dimension of the subspace is the number of elements of basis. In this case the third is really a linear combination of two others:

$-1 (1,3,-1,2,3) + (2,7,-2,5,2) = (1,4,-1,3,-1)$

but the first and second one are linearly independent, So the basis is

$\{ (1,3,-1,2,3), (2,7,-2,5,2)\}$

and the dimension is $2$. note that complement of $W$ is not a vector space as it does not contain the $0$, adding the $0$ also may not make it a subspace. Let's think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for easier imagination, assume $W$ be the $x=y$ line, is complement of $W$ an interesting set? Not at all. So speaking about a vector subspace complement usually doesn't make sense, instead it's better to think about *Orthogonal complement*, you may find more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).

Comment: Thank you very much a lot. How can I find a basis for complement of W? Do I need to first find by hand complement of W and then do the same operations again?

Comment: The complement of W is not a vector space and therefore does not have a basis.

Comment: I mean the orthogonal complement sorry.

Comment: Oh right, [this link](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/find-a-basis-for-the-orthogonal-complement-of-the-subspace-of-rn-spanned-by-the-vectors-v1-1-4-5-6-9/) may help.

Comment: I found the basis for orthogonal complement of W as (1,-1,0,1,0),(-15,4,0,0,1) can you confirm it ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not true, the sum of dimensions of a subspace and it's orthogonal complement should be the dimension of whole space (5 here), so you may find a basis made of 3 linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I write the vectors as rows and reduced it to row echelon form and then solved for the AX=0 what is the problem ? What should be the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to find the orthogonal complement but I think this is not a good example to work on. I think extending the basis of $W$ to basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ and use gram-schmidt orthogonalization process, should solve the problem, but as I tried the numbers will become very unpleasant (fractional and irrational).

Comment: Actually the question doesn't want me to find orthogonal complement. It wants me to find a basis for orthogonal complemet of W from row space null space theorem I guess.

Comment: The problem of finding a vector space is finding it's basis I guess and there is no difference but I'm not sure, but as I said I'm not quite familiar with orthogonal complements, It would be a great idea to ask this as another question in the site.

Answer (score 0):

You write : " I know I will create a matrix by using vectors as columns of matrix and reduce it to row echelon form ".
Just do it :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 7 &  4\\
-1 & -2 & -1 \\
 2& 5 &  3\\
3 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3& 1 &  1\\
-1 & 0 &  0\\
 2& 1 & 1 \\
3 & -4 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
(c2-2*c1;c3-c1)$$ So,...